# Pull data from one Google spreadsheet to another using Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have 2 spreadsheet in my Drive. I want to pull data from a cell in 1 spreadsheet and copy it in another.
The spreadsheet "TestUsage" will sometimes have data in column A, but none is column B.
I would like so that when I open the spreadsheet, it would populate that empty cell in sheet "TestUsage" from sheet "TestParts".
Here is my code:

```
var ssTestUsage = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sTestUsage = ssTestUsage.getActiveSheet();
var lastRowTestUsage = sTestUsage.getLastRow();
var rangeTestUsage = sTestUsage.getSheetValues(1, 1, lastRowTestUsage, 4);
var TESTPARTS_ID = "1NjaFo0Y_MR2uvwit1WuNeRfc7JCOyukaKZhuraWNmKo";
var ssTestParts = SpreadsheetApp.openById(TESTPARTS_ID);
var sTestParts = ssTestParts.getSheets()[0];
var lastRowTestParts = sTestParts.getLastRow();
var rangeTestParts = sTestParts.getSheetValues(1, 1, lastRowTestParts, 3);

function onOpen() {
  for (i = 2; i < lastRowTestUsage; i++) {
    if (rangeTestUsage[i][0] !== "" && rangeTestUsage[i][1] == "") {
      for (j = 1; j < lastRowTestParts; j++) {
        if (rangeTestUsage[i][0] == rangeTestParts[j][0]) {
          Logger.log(rangeTestUsage[i][1]);
          Logger.log(rangeTestParts[j][1]);
          rangeTestUsage[i][1] = rangeTestParts[j][1];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this is this doesn't do anything:

```
rangeTestUsage[i][1] = rangeTestParts[j][1];
```

I know there must be a method that can get data from one range to another.
Please let me know if I am totally incorrect or I am on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serge insas has a good explanation of why your code doesn't work and hints at the solution below.

I recommend you use an array to store the updated values of column B that you want then set the entire column at the end.

#### Modifying your code...

```
var ssTestUsage = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sTestUsage = ssTestUsage.getActiveSheet();
var lastRowTestUsage = sTestUsage.getLastRow();
var rangeTestUsage = sTestUsage.getSheetValues(1, 1, lastRowTestUsage, 2);
var TESTPARTS_ID = "1NjaFo0Y_MR2uvwit1WuNeRfc7JCOyukaKZhuraWNmKo";
var ssTestParts = SpreadsheetApp.openById(TESTPARTS_ID);
var sTestParts = ssTestParts.getSheets()[0];
var lastRowTestParts = sTestParts.getLastRow();
var rangeTestParts = sTestParts.getSheetValues(1, 1, lastRowTestParts, 2);

var colB = [];

function onOpen() {
  for (i = 2; i < lastRowTestUsage; i++) {
    if (rangeTestUsage[i][0] !== "" && rangeTestUsage[i][1] == "") {
      var matched = false;
      for (j = 1; j < lastRowTestParts; j++) {
        if (rangeTestUsage[i][0] == rangeTestParts[j][0]) {
          //Logger.log(rangeTestUsage[i][1]);
          //Logger.log(rangeTestParts[j][1]);
          colB.push([rangeTestParts[j][1]]); // push the value we want into colB array
          matched = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(!matched) // this is in case you don't have a match
        colB.push([""]); // incase we don't have a matching part
    } else {
      colB.push([rangeTestUsage[i][0]]); // we already have a value we want so just add that to colB array
    }
  }
  sTestUsage.getRange(2,2,lastRowTestUsage).setValues(colB); // update entire column b with values in colB array
}
```

Comment: @Gene-Thanks, but you are making a (small) mistake creating the output array... The resulting array must be a 2 dimension array, in the case of a single column it look like `[[''],[''],[''],[''],[''],['']]` so instead of simply pushing `value` you should push `[value]` to get a useable result.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer did just what I wanted. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

the statement

"this doesn't do anything:"

```
rangeTestUsage[i][1] = rangeTestParts[j][2];
```

is not really true... and not really false neither..., actually it does assign the value to rangeTestUsage[i](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) but you dont see it because it is not reflected in the spreadsheet.

Both values are taken from the Sheet using `getValues` so at that time they are both array elements.

What is missing is just writing back the array to the sheet using the symetrical statement `setValues()`

Give it a try and don't hesitate to come back if something goes wrong.

**EDIT :**

I didn't notice at first that you were using `getSheetValues` instead of `getValues` (simply because I never use this one)... the only difference is that getValues is a method of the [range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) while yours belongs to the [sheet class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en); the syntax is similar in a way, just use

```
Sheet.getRange(row,col,width,height).getValues()
```

it takes one word more but has the advantage to have a direct equivalent to set values

`Sheet.getRange(row,col,width,height).setValues()`